# Is there a way of knowing if `.repeat`/`.batch`/`.shuffle` have been used on a tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, eager-execution

One gets an already built tensorflow dataset object (`tf.data.Dataset`) named `data`.

Is there a way to know if the function `repeat`/`batch`/`shuffle` was called on this object, **by inspecting data** ? (and possibly get other informations like the argument of batch and repeat)

(I assume eager execution)

**edit 1:** seems line the str method carries some information. Looking into that.

**edit 2:** the attribute output_shapes give information on the batch size and shapes.

Comment: batch_size can be retrieved by calling get_next obviously.

Comment: define "by inspecting data ?"  You mean by looking at the output?

Comment: I mean by looking at the attributes/methods of the object data

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of is getting into tensorflow code. `gen_dataset_ops.py` is generated during building from source, so it could only be found locally.

Another file is `dataset_ops.py`, it's available in the link below. You just insert print statement before relevant function's return. For example shuffle function from `dataset_ops.py`:

```
def shuffle(self, buffer_size, seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=None):
"""Randomly shuffles the elements of this dataset.
...
print('Dataset shuffled') #inserted print here
return ShuffleDataset(self, buffer_size, seed, reshuffle_each_iteration)
```

Dataset object is wrapped into `DatasetV1Adapter`, so you can't know anything about it advance. The only difference in eager mode is that it supports explicit iteration, but it'll be extremely inefficient to do smth like

```
array = np.random.rand(10)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(array)
if len([i for i in dataset]) != array.shape[0]:
    print('repeated')
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py

Comment: We don't have access to array

Comment: We only have the dataset object

Comment: This is more a counter example. I updated answer, this is rough but it works

Comment: I think you should remove in your answer the part about the eager mode. It is misleading.

Comment: Maybe it comes from my question not being explicit.

Comment: Should be clear now. eager mode doesn't matter in this case